# Why does rounding up of the number doesn't work here?(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for _ in range(3):
sec=sec+1.3
round(sec)
print(sec)
```

I am working on a GUI/ML project and i ran the above simple snippet.I have to display the number in the GUI(pyqt5) but the output is all messed up.Here is the output that i got.(sec=0 at the start obviously)

1. 1.3
2. 2.6
3. 3.9000000000000004

Questions:-

1. Why is the output 3.9000000000000004??Why the anomaly??
2. I have tried multiple ways to round up the number like ....but nothing works!! How can i round this upto 1/2 decimal places???

Comment: Try `round (sec, 1)`. Does it show a better format?

Answer (score 0):

`round(x)` doesn't alter the value of `x`, it returns the rounded `x`

```
for _ in range(3):
    sec=sec+1.3
    sec_rounded = round(sec)
    print(sec_rounded)
```

Should do the trick

Comment: oh stupid mistake from my side! Thanks for the answer and the similar question feedback